# Denying a PHP class to be inherited or used

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

For my project I have created a folder named DBAccess which holds all database related PHP files having PHP classes,constants functions etc.In the outside of the folder I have created a php file named DBAccess.php.
following is my directory structur in short

```
Project1
  |_DBAccess
  |       |_functions.php
  |       |_class.php
  |       |_constants.php         
  |_DBAccess.php
  |_index.php
  |_aboutus.php  
    .......
```

Now i wish to restrict any pages in the root directory to use the contents of the DBAccess folder except the DBAccess.php file.Is it posssible in PHP using .htaccess or something else?

Comment: Why?! *Some* PHP code has to use these files, otherwise they're useless (literally). Just don't use those files in other code, you don't need to protect yourself from yourself that much.

Comment: +1, but I'm looking forward to knowing the answer to this question!

Comment: And since you wrote the class and those pages then you can simply decide not to include your class in those pages you mentioned, why "protection"

Comment: Using "final class", which disallows extending the class, is as far as you can go with restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

DebugAccess/foo.php

```
<?php
$trace = debug_backtrace();

if (isset($trace[0])) {
  $dir =  basename(dirname($trace[0]['file']));
  $file = basename($trace[0]['file']);
  if ($file != 'DBAccess.php' && $dir != 'DBAccess') {
    throw new Exception("Nice try butthead");
  }
}

echo "Access Granted\n";
```

---

DBAccess.php

```
<?php
include_once("DBAccess/foo.php");
```

---

NoDBAccess.php

```
<?php
include_once("DBAccess/foo.php");
```

---

```
> php DBAccess.php 
Access Granted

> php NoDBAccess.php 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Nice try butthead' in /Users/seanberry/so/DBAccess/foo.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/seanberry/so/NoDBAccess.php(3): include_once()
#1 {main}
```

Comment: You *really* don't want your code to be testable (or reusable for that matter)?

Comment: I just answered the question.  I didn't mention that I thought it was a **bad** idea, which I do.

Comment: This is the right solution to a bad question. @sberry also you should take into account that files from inside the DBAccess folder may call other files/functions from this folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that takes care of this and all you have to do is to call that function in _DBAccess.php or in any other file which you require access to these files.

Try this function:

```
function include_all_php($folder){
    foreach (glob("{$folder}/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        require $filename;
    }
}
```

And then you will only have to call that function with the foldername.

```
include_all_php("_DBAccess")
```

And if you wish files to not include these files, then don't require them :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can :

a) By defining a global variable in DBAccess.php e.g

```
define('DB_LIB',true)
```

and using DB_LIB constant in all other files in folders

(bit cheep trick but this ensures that those files are not directly accessed out of context)

b) Stop inheritance by defining the [class as final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php)

**Indirectly answers the question**

c) Stop re-inventing the wheel ( if you are creating an access layer as your example is suggesting )
  and use already existing one [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

d) Use some suitable OO design patterns [e.g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) and check [this also](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/) . 
  Your reaction will be why ? Because using a pattern will fix lots of inheritance and dependency issues e.g in case of access layer , a child object will not be instantiated unless its not created with dependent objects e.g in factory case

f) make user of of [public , private and protected keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: You beat me to it while was typing. :)

Comment: This does not work, because once the DBAccess.php is loaded, this constant is defined, and other files would be able to call files in the DBAccess folder, because the constant is already defined. Setting the class as final is the good approach to stop inheritance though.

Comment: yes you are right therefore,  I said `out of context` `accessing directly`

Answer (score 0):

- `.htaccess` has nothing to do with PHP, it is a settings file for the Apache web server. Apache cannot prevent PHP code from reading files on disk.
- You can prevent *accidental* access by, e.g., requiring certain constant to be defined:

  ```
  // DBAccess.php
  define('CAN_ACCESS_DB', true);

  // functions.php
  if( !defined('CAN_ACCESS_DB') ){
      die('You are not allowed to access this file');
  }
  ```

  ... but there's no way to prevent intentional access.

Your best chance is probably to rethink your design.